# Find position of HTML tag content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have task, and can't find out how to make it.

So, i have such string:

```html
<td class="class1">
 <span class="class1"></span>
</td>
<td class="class1">
 <span>0</span>
</td>
<td class="class1">
 <span class="class1">1</span>
</td>
<td class="class1">
 <span class="class1">0</span>
</td>
```

I need to find the index of each span tag content in string.

Comment: When you say position do you mean what index in the source the span tag starts at?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: Yeap, sorry i mean index. And no this link didn't help me.

Comment: What are you needing to find this index for exactly?

Comment: Developer advice: if you need to use HTML as string and/or regex on HTML, you're doing it wrong. Consider using an HTML parser.

Comment: @dmikester1, i want to replace content of span with some other values.

Comment: @NinoFiliu, agree with you, but in this task i have such conditions.

Comment: yes, there are much much easier methods that looking for the index of each span

Comment: @YuraLukashchuk if your goal is to replace the content inside the span tags, please include those details in your original post.  That will help people out in answering your question.

Comment: @YuraLukashchuk If all you are wanting to do is replace the content inside the span tags, you have no need to find the index of all the span tags.  A simple for loop setting the textContent of each span is all you need similar to what Scott posted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to do this and it really smells like a bad idea to manipulate HTML as string, but hey, if you need some code, here you go:

```js
const needle = '<span';
const haystack = `<td class="class1">
  <span class="class1"></span>
</td>
<td class="class1">
  <span>0</span>
</td>
<td class="class1">
  <span class="class1">1</span>
</td>
<td class="class1">
  <span class="class1">0</span>
</td>`;
const indices = (new Array(haystack.length))
  .fill()
  .map((_,i) => i)
  .filter(i => haystack.substr(i,needle.length)==needle);

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an actual `String`, then we can take that an load it up into a temporary element to turn it into DOM nodes. Then, we can query the temporary container and get the index quite easily:

```js
let myString = `<td class="class1">
   <span class="class1"></span>
 </td>
 <td class="class1">
   <span>0</span>
 </td>
 <td class="class1">
   <span class="class1">1</span>
 </td>
 <td class="class1">
   <span class="class1">0</span>
 </td>`;
 
 let tempElement = document.createElement("tr");
 tempElement.innerHTML = myString; // Parse the string as HTML into the row
 let spans = tempElement.querySelectorAll("span"); // Gather up the spans
 
 for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
   console.log("The span at index " + i + " has text of: " +spans[i].textContent);
 }
```

If you don't have a `String`, but instead just have those elements as part of your page, the process is the same, just without setting up the temporary container element:

```js
let spans = document.querySelectorAll("span"); // Gather up the spans
 
 for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
   console.log("The span at index " + i + " has text of: " +spans[i].textContent);
      spans[i].textContent = "Whatever you want";
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="class1">
     <span class="class1"></span>
    </td>
    <td class="class1">
      <span>0</span>
    </td>
    <td class="class1">
      <span class="class1">1</span>
    </td>
    <td class="class1">
      <span class="class1">0</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: From the comments above, it looks like he just wants to replace the html in the span.  So inside the for loop, you could put something like `spans[i].innerHTML = 'new content';`

Comment: @dmikester1 There is no HTML in the span, it's text, so `.textContent` should be used. But, the OP has given us no indication of what he intends to do, he asks how to get the index and that's what I'm showing.

Comment: Aw, didn't realize that about the HTML.  In the comments above he says " i want to replace content of span with some other values."